# Delete all Orders, Sales & Customer Data in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer-account

How can i delete all Orders, Sales & Customer Data in Magento website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and worked for me on my server.

#### Tested on Magento CE 1.4.1.1 - 1.9.1.1

```
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    ##############################
    # SALES RELATED TABLES
    ##############################
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;            
    TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;        
    TRUNCATE `log_quote`;

    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    #########################################
    # DOWNLOADABLE PURCHASED
    #########################################
    TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
    TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;

    ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    #########################################
    # RESET ID COUNTERS
    #########################################
    TRUNCATE `eav_entity_store`;
    ALTER TABLE  `eav_entity_store` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    ##############################
    # CUSTOMER RELATED TABLES
    ##############################
    TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_int`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_text`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_entity`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_entity_datetime`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_entity_decimal`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_entity_int`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_entity_text`;
    TRUNCATE `customer_entity_varchar`;
    TRUNCATE `tag`;
    TRUNCATE `tag_relation`;
    TRUNCATE `tag_summary`;
    TRUNCATE `tag_properties`;        ## CHECK ME
    TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
    TRUNCATE `log_customer`;

    ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `tag_properties` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `log_customer` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    ##############################
    # ADDITIONAL LOGS
    ##############################
    TRUNCATE `log_url`;
    TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
    TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
    TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
    TRUNCATE `report_event`;
    TRUNCATE `report_viewed_product_index`;
    TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
    ##? TRUNCATE `log_summary`

    ALTER TABLE `log_url` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `log_url_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
    ##? ALTER TABLE `log_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been tested and confirmed working on Magento versions from 1.4.0.1 to 1.9.1.1.

```
# Tested on Magento CE 1.4.1.1 - 1.9.1.1

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

##############################
# SALES RELATED TABLES
##############################
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;            # ??
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;        # ??
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

#########################################
# DOWNLOADABLE PURCHASED
#########################################
TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;

ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

#########################################
# RESET ID COUNTERS
#########################################
TRUNCATE `eav_entity_store`;
ALTER TABLE  `eav_entity_store` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


##############################
# CUSTOMER RELATED TABLES
##############################
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE `tag`;
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`;
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`;
TRUNCATE `tag_properties`;            ## CHECK ME
TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE `log_customer`;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `tag_properties` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_customer` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


##############################
# ADDITIONAL LOGS
##############################
TRUNCATE `log_url`;
TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;
TRUNCATE `report_viewed_product_index`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
### ??? TRUNCATE `log_summary`

ALTER TABLE `log_url` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_url_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
### ??? ALTER TABLE `log_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

For more information check [Cleanly Delete all Orders, Sales & Customer Data](https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2014/08/cleanly-delete-orders-sales-customer-data-magento/)

Hope this helps